# MATLAB relu "Incorrect number or types of inputs or outputs for function relu"

Tags: matlab, relu

I'm trying to use the relu function on a matrix in MATLAB, and am calling it as `A = relu(A)`, but I keep getting the error

> Incorrect number or types of inputs or outputs for function relu.

I tried it on a scalar as well, and also get the same error. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MATLAB, [`relu`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/dlarray.relu.html) is a *method* of [`dlarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/dlarray.html). So you need to pass in a `dlarray` instance as input, like this:

```matlab
out = relu(dlarray(1)) % or whatever value you wish
```

Comment: ... and yes, that error message is far from ideal. It's far too easy to overlook the ".. or types.." piece, and what that's trying to tell you.